# Error in laravel how clear this division by zero

Tags: php, laravel, division, zero

here is the code with division by zero in laravel

```php
$multi_cotas = Variavel::where('ativo', true)->first()->multi_cotas;
$f_saldo_cotas = Fabrica::all()->first()->saldo_cotas;
$num_cotas = 0;
$graduacoes = Graduacao::all();
foreach ($graduacoes as $graduacao) {
    $num_cotas += $graduacao->total_cotas_qualificados;
}
$num_cotas = $num_cotas * $multi_cotas;
$valor_cota = $f_saldo_cotas / $num_cotas;
$planos = Plano::where('ativo', true)->get();
return view('dashboard.user-dashboard', compact('planos', 'valor_cota'));
```

Comment: you must add logic to do something different when `$num_cotas` = 0..!   Probably what is happening is that `$graduacao->total_cotas_qualificados` = 0 or `$multi_cotas` = 0.  How should you calculate `$valor_cota` in that case?

Comment: basically, before you can do this: `$valor_cota = $f_saldo_cotas/$num_cotas;`  you must ensure that `$num_cotas` is not zero!

Comment: `if ($num_cotas !== 0)  $valor_cota = $f_saldo_cotas/$num_cotas; else { /* handle error */ }`

Answer (score 0):

you could try to check if $f_saldo_cotas or $num_cotas is equal to 0.

For example:

```
$valor_cota = $f_saldo_cotas != 0 && $num_cotas != 0 ? $f_saldo_cotas/$num_cotas : 0;
```